# Meta tags missing on Next.js pages that use dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building a website using Next.js 10, and I've run into an issue that has me stumped.

I'm trying to add meta tags to individual pages. I've created a "Meta" component that contains the meta tags I want to add to each page. When I import it into pages that do not use dynamic routing, the meta tags are added to the page and can be seen in "View Source". When I import the component into pages that use dynamic routing, however, none of the meta tags get added to the page.

I've found other questions on Stack Overflow that seem to reference a similar issue, but none of them have answers. I've also tried using the [next-seo](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo) module, but I see the same issue: meta tags appear properly on pages that don't use dynamic routing but do not appear on pages that use dynamic routing.

I'm not using a _page.js.

Here's my Meta component:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

const Meta = () => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta name='description' content='A description.' />
    </Head>
  )
}

export default Meta
```

And a page that uses dynamic routes where the meta tag *is not* getting added properly:

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { addApolloState, initializeApollo } from '../../lib/apolloClient'
import App from '../../components/App'
import Meta from '../../components/Meta'
import { Queries } from '../../graphql/Queries.js'
import ErrorMessage from '../../components/ErrorMessage'

const MyPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(Queries.Get, {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      skip: !slug,
      variables: {
        slug: slug
      }
    }
  )

  if (!slug) return <></>
  if (error) return <ErrorMessage message='Error loading.' />
  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <App>
      <Meta />
      <div>
        <p>Testing.</p>
      </div>
    </App>
  )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    fallback: true,
    paths: []
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()
  const { params } = context
  const { slug } = params

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: Queries.Get,
    variables: {
      slug: slug
    }
  })

  return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
    props: {},
    revalidate: 1
  })
}

export default MyPage
```

I'm happy to add the code for a page that doesn't use dynamic routing (where the meta tag gets added properly), but it's more or less identical other than the `useRouter` and `router.query` lines.

---

Here's my `App` component:

```
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Header from '../components/Header'

export default function App ({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col h-screen'>
      <Header />
      <main className='flex-1'>
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code in one of my dymnamic pages. There it works. Also, I did something similar with a custom *<Head />* Component and also did not have any problems. On which next version are you? I am on **"next": "^10.0.4"**.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on that same version. Funny though... I pushed the app to Vercel and the `<Head />` component works fine there. So it seems like this is just an issue when running locally. Beats me why that would be the case though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your `App` component contain? Does removing it from that page fix the meta tag showing?

Comment: @juliomalves: Just added the code for my `App` component. It's super simple.